# How do I NOT publish my SharePoint changes?

Tags: sharepoint

I am new to SharePoint.

I have modified a production page using "Edit Page" and have messed up the layout of the page. The data is still intact but the format in sorry shape. The pages status is: "Checked out and editable. Publication Start Date: Immediately". I do not want to publish the page.

Every time I go back to the page, it shows me the same Status even after I shut down my browser and open a new browser.

I do not want to Publish my changes. Is there a way to kill my session and the changes, so I can have someone with more experience at work show me the proper way to make the changes?

Thanks.

Comment: And you did this using the Gui in SharePoint or using SharePoint designer, also is this SharePoint 2007, 2010 or 2013?

Comment: Using the GUI Ribbon on SharePoint 2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options here. Most items including Pages in SharePoint are simply stored as list items or library items and changes may be revoked

1. when items are checked out
2. if you have versioning enabled

You will have the most options if you find your page library, this will be visible in the "All Site Content" listing (~/_layouts/viewlsts.aspx); http://sharepointserver.com/siteurl/_layouts/viewlsts.aspx.

In the most common scenarios it will be here (~/SitePages/Forms/AllPages.aspx) http://sharepointserver.com/siteurl/SitePages/Forms/AllPages.aspx.

**Discard Check Out**

Note the item (page) I selected and the "Discard Check Out" in the ribbon menu.

[image]

**Versions**

Check version history on the item, restore any stored version you want to.

[image]

If none of these options are there you have run out of luck. There may possibly be a content backup but I'd say it will be easier to actually manually restore the page in such scenario.

Comment: Thanks I know enough now what to ask for when talking to the main administrator.